# whois TCP socket connection fails for one server

Tags: perl, sockets, tcp, whois

I'm writing a short script to query domain names from their respective whois servers - while in most cases, while the TCP connection via port 43 seems to be working for most whois servers, the queries to `whois.markmonitor.com` seems to be failing with an odd error that says *Invalid query*.

Here's the barebones of what I'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#whois.pl

use strict;
use IO::Socket;

my $domain_name = "google.com";
my $query_socket = new IO::Socket::INET(
        PeerAddr => 'whois.iana.org',
        PeerPort => 43,
        Proto => 'tcp');
print $query_socket "$domain_name ";
print $query_socket "\n\r";
while(my $this_line = <$query_socket>) {
        print $this_line;
}
close($query_socket);
```

As seen above, the whois server used is `whois.iana.org`; this also works as expected with `whois.internic.net` as well. Only in the case of `whois.markmonitor.com`, the following error is seen:

```
$ perl whois.pl 
Invalid query
```

Could someone help shed more light on how can I perhaps get a more verbose output to check if there are any  errors in the query that is being made to the server?

As an added test, a normal connection via `telnet` seems to be working as expected as seen below:

```
$ telnet whois.markmonitor.com 43
Trying 64.124.14.21...
Connected to whois.markmonitor.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
google.com
Domain Name: google.com
Registry Domain ID: 2138514_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.markmonitor.com
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2015-06-12T10:38:52-0700
Creation Date: 1997-09-15T00:00:00-0700
......<output truncated>......
```

which leads me to believe that the actual connections to the server via port 43 are being accepted on the server's side.

Comment: I guess this is due to the extra space character in `"$domain_name "`

Comment: Either that or it doesn't like `\r\n`

Answer (score 1):

As [artistoex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345520/artistoex) notes - it's because there's a space in your domain name. 
Change your print line to:

```
print {$query_socket} "$domain_name\n";
```

(Note - the curly braces are for style reasons and can be omitted - I prefer them to make clear this is a file handle)

Answer (score 0):

Per [RFC3912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3912.txt) the client is expected to communicate like that in `whois` protocol: "All requests are terminated with ASCII CR and then ASCII LF"

So in your code, instead of `"\n\r"` please use `"\r\n"`. And remove the extra space like written in other replies.

Note however that `whois`is not a well defined structured protocol: do not expect all whois servers to work in the same way nor to adhere to some kind of standards. You will find a lot of strange cases...